# WiFi not connecting and locked

Tags: wireless

The wifi connection to my Xubuntu box has become locked. The dropdown from the wifi logo in the task bar shows a padlock symbol overlaying the usual wifi radial symbol.
 The hard lock switch on the box is off and I've tried upgrading the kernel which was one recommendation, and updating the `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` file which was another, but no effect. I also looked in the BIOS to see if I could find a solution there, but all seemed in order as far as I could tell.
 The hub/modem is OK as other computers are getting connection, and my box is connecting just fine with a cable - and also wireless connects OK to the printer.
 Any help welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look for a function key (F!- F12) that turns on and turns off your wireless device. I went thru a recent experience where I believed I lost wireless and later discovered I had actually turned wireless off with F2 on my laptop. Hope this simple fix does the trick.

Comment: As I mentioned, I'd tried looking at that and I even turned the F2 setting on and off to be sure. It also connects to the printer by wifi. When it's off, wifi options no longer appears in the drop-down from the link in the task bar. Turned on again and the options re=-appear.

Comment: Problem solved with the latest update from Ubuntu, which contained replacement  kernel. After restarting following the update, the wifi was working fine, even though the task bar icon still showed a padlock symbol.